# Interchange of limit and integral for a positive random variable with finite moments.

Tags: limits, probability-distributions

Let $f$ be the pdf of a non-negative random variable $X$ with finite moments of all orders, i.e. $E[X^n]<+\infty$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. May I interchange the limit with the integral and infer that $$\lim_{w\to \infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}xf(x+w)\mathop{dx}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot\lim_{w\to \infty}f(x+w)\mathop{dx}=0$$

Comment: What are your thoughts/attempts?

Comment: The integral inside the limit in the LHS is $E((X-w)^+)$ hence...

Comment: @Math1000 I am trying to use the dominated convergence theorem with $f_w(x)=xf(x+w)$ but I cannot find an integrable $g(x)$ that dominates all  of $f_w(x)$. I know that $xf(x)$ is integrable, but does this imply that also $xf(x+w)$ is also integrable?

Comment: @Did. Thank you. So I can argue that since $E(X-w)^+\le E(X)$ which is finite then I may bring the limit inside the integral? Do I use the dominated convergence theorem? Sorry, I know it is easy, but I am stuck for some reason.

Comment: Yes, Lebesgue DCT, but the argument is that $(X-w)^+\leqslant X$ pointwise with $X$ integrable, not that $E((X-w)^+)\leqslant E(X)$.

Comment: @Did Ok, I see it know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on @Did's comments, by a change of variables we see that
$$\mathbb E[(X-w)^+] = \int_0^\infty (x-w)^+f(x)\mathsf dx = \int_0^\infty xf(x+w)\mathsf dx. $$
Since $X\geqslant0$, $0\leqslant(X-w)^+\leqslant X$ for all $w\geqslant 0$, and as $X\in\mathcal L^1$, by dominated convergence we have that
$$\lim_{w\to\infty}\mathbb E[(X-w)^+] = \mathbb E\left[\lim_{w\to\infty}(X-w)^+\right].$$
Since $\mathbb E[X]<\infty$, for any $\omega$, we may choose $w$ such that $w>X(\omega)$, and hence $$\lim_{w\to\infty}(X-w)^+=0.$$

It follows that

$$\lim_{w\to\infty}\int_0^\infty xf(x+w)\mathsf dx = \mathbb E\left[\lim_{w\to\infty}(X-w)^+\right] = 0.$$